# Cassandra opscenter not connecting to local cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, ubuntu-16.04, opscenter

The datastax has restricted the use of opscenter for enterprise users only. Is there any  way or possibility that even an open source casandra user can have access to the opscenter? Kindly check the follwing image and let me know if there is any possibility of the usage or opscenter?
I am trying to connect it but gettng the following error:

[image: Problem figure]

Answer (score 2):

No. However you could consider creating a monitor via the metrics exposed by JMX instead.